# Pip can't install packages in Vagrant box, and it says there's a cymem file missing that isn't

Tags: python, pip, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant to edit a Python project on Windows that was written on Linux machines. This is the text of the Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.name = "medaCy_box"
  end

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
    python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip3 install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm-2.0.0
    pip3 install -e /vagrant
SHELL
end
```

When it provisions, these two lines from the console stand out:

```
/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 4:  2903 Killed pip3 install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm-2.0.0

/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 5:  2911 Killed     pip3 install -e /vagrant
```

I decided to SSH into Vagrant and run those two steps from the command line there to see if I'd get more information. I also tried installing some of the dependencies of the package that this is for individually. Any time I attempted to install a package with pip3, I got one or both of these two error messages:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cymem-2.0.2.dist-info/RECORD'
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cymem-2.0.2.dist-info/METADATA'
```

Given the apparent importance of cymem, I tried installing that and got this error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: cymem in /home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.0.2)
No metadata found in /home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cymem-2.0.2.dist-info/METADATA'
```

I navigated to `/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cymem-2.0.2.dist-info/`, and the METADATA file is in fact there and is non-empty.

I don't know why I would be having an issue pertaining to that file not existing when I was able to navigate to and open it. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is `/vagrant` and not just `vagrant`?

Comment: @drum, I believe that line was correct because if I SSH into Vagrant, cd to the root, and run `$ pip3 install -e /vagrant`, it begins the installation, ending with the error message posted above. Thank you for your response.